# Kill a chain of sub processes on KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm having a strange problem I've encountered as I wrote a script to start my local JBoss instance.

My code looks something like this:

```
with open("/var/run/jboss/jboss.pid", "wb") as f:
    process = subprocess.Popen(["/opt/jboss/bin/standalone.sh", "-b=0.0.0.0"])
    f.write(str(process.pid))

    try:
        process.wait()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        process.kill()
```

Should be fairly simple to understand, write the PID to a file while its running, once I get a `KeyboardInterrupt`, kill the child process.

The problem is that JBoss keeps running in the background after I send the kill signal, as it seems that the signal doesn't propagate down to the Java process started by `standalone.sh`.

I like the idea of using Python to write system management scripts, but there are a lot of weird edge cases like this where if I would have written it in Bash, everything would have just worked™.

How can I kill the entire subprocess tree when I get a `KeyboardInterrupt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the [`psutil`](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#) library:

```
import psutil

#..

proc = psutil.Process(process.pid)
for child in proc.children(recursive=True):
    child.kill()

proc.kill()
```

As far as I know the `subprocess` module does not offer any API function to retrieve the children spawned by subprocesses, nor does the `os` module.

---

A better way of killing the processes would probably be the following:

```
proc = psutil.Process(process.pid)
procs = proc.children(recursive=True)
procs.append(proc)

for proc in procs:
    proc.terminate()

gone, alive = psutil.wait_procs(procs, timeout=1)
for p in alive:
    p.kill()
```

This would give a chance to the processes to terminate correctly and when the timeout ends the remaining processes will be killed.

---

Note that `psutil` also provides a `Popen` class that has the same interface of `subprocess.Popen` *plus* all the extra functionality of `psutil.Process`. You may want to simply use that instead of `subprocess.Popen`. It is also *safer* because `psutil` checks that PIDs don't get reused if a process terminates, while `subprocess` doesn't.